# astra theme costum css not working in wordpress 5.6

Tags: css

I am using the Astra theme and in additional CSS when I use CSS to change color for the `p` tag it works fine. I want to change the color of `h1` tags but the custom CSS is not working. I have tried:

```
h1 {
    color: purple;
}
```

I am using free version not pro what should I do?

Comment: You should ask this question in the Astra theme support forums, please.

Comment: Try more specificity in your selectors... ...so instead of `h1{color:purple;}` try `.parent-class-name > h1.class-name{color:purple;}`... ...that's just a guess because you haven't provided any code for us to attempt to assist you with.  That's always a good start and, as Q Studio suggested, you should first contact the Astra dev's and support forum.